# What's 'none too well known?'

Tags: word-usage, grammar

One of the questions I came across reads:

> The topography of the ocean floors ***none too well known,*** since in great areas the available soundings are hundreds or even thousands of miles apart.

What sort of *syntax* it is? Initially, I thought that it's ***not too well known***. But when checked the source, it wasn't that.

What's the difference between *not too well known* and *none too well known?* Is there any?

Comment: In my opinion, 'none too well known' means 'not any too well known', so it is surely different from 'not too well known'. And I think 'none too well known' emphasizes 'not at all', but 'not too well known' doesn't.

Comment: None too means not very. For example, the food is none too good. I posted a similar question before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, there's a verb - probably *are* - missing between the words *floors* and *none*.

But in answer to your question, the expression *none too* is a popular way of saying *not too* and often, *not very*.

One frequently comes across: *none too soon*, meaning *just in time*.

To say that someone is *none too bright* would mean not very clever.

You will find explanations and examples at many sites (google *none too*), including:

https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/none+too